# How to build pysparse on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, sparse-matrix

When I try to install pysparse via `pip install pysparse==1.3-dev`, the build fails with the error:

```
pysparse/sparse/src/spmatrixmodule.c:4:22: fatal error: spmatrix.h: No such file or directory
```

These kinds of errors are usually the result of some missing system dev package, but googling doesn't show anything for "spmatrix". I tried installing the `python-sparse` package, which does provide this file, but I still get the same error.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this dev-1.3 pakage there were no ".h" and ".c" files if you go through their source.
Use `pip install pysparse==1.2-dev213` or lower versions or `pip install csc-pysparse`

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Kind of messy of the developers to leave it in a somewhat broken state.