# Cannot find numpy._import_tools when testing pysparse

Tags: python, numpy, fipy

After [installing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25459011/2173773) `pysparse` with Python version 2.7.15:

```
$ pyenv local 2.7.15
$ pip install pysparse==1.2-dev213
```

I tried to test the installation as shown at the `pysparse` [home page](http://pysparse.sourceforge.net/introduction.html). But when I run the test
`testSuperlu.py`, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testSuperlu.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pysparse.tools import poisson
  File "/home/hakon/.pyenv/versions/2.7.15/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysparse/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from numpy._import_tools import PackageLoader
ImportError: No module named _import_tools
```

It seems like `numpy._import_tools` is missing. I am using
`numpy` version 1.16.0.

**Edit**:

After following the advice from @wd15 in their answer below, i.e. installing different versions of `pyparse` and `numpy`:

```
$ pip install pysparse==1.1.1-dev
$ pip install numpy==1.15.1
```

Then running the test program `testSuperlu.py` again:

```
$ python testSuperlu.py
ImportError: No module named _multiarray_umath
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testSuperlu.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pysparse.tools import poisson
  File "/home/hakon/.pyenv/versions/2.7.15/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysparse/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from sparse import spmatrix
  File "/home/hakon/.pyenv/versions/2.7.15/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysparse/sparse/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pysparseMatrix import *
  File "/home/hakon/.pyenv/versions/2.7.15/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysparse/sparse/pysparseMatrix.py", line 57, in <module>
    from pysparse.sparse import spmatrix
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

Comment: In my 1.15 installation, this file is at /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/_import_tools.py'

Comment: @hpaulj Yes I also have that file for my Python 3 installation (using `pyenv`), but for Python 2 the file is missing (in folder: `/home/hakon/.pyenv/versions/2.7.15/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy`)

Comment: `pysparse` is rather old - 2013

Comment: @hpaulj Yes I know its old :) but I have no choice, I need to install [FiPy](https://github.com/usnistgov/fipy). This package uses Python 2 and also the `pysparse` package..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FiPy now has a [Nix recipe](https://github.com/usnistgov/fipy/tree/develop/nix), which fixes the versions of PySparse and Numpy to be compatible. The Nix recipe uses version 1.1.1-dev of PySparse ([hosted here](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f3/a5/f1b6d0fac5bf45729e8099bd1eef039b0c7c37f8324f3be7d5e9253bb504/pysparse-1.1.1-dev.tar.gz)) along with version 1.15.1 of Numpy ([hosted here](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/65/ab/4dfcc20234fae12ee40c714b98077d6e3a10652496bd1488fa4828529b22/numpy-1.15.1.zip)).

If you don't want to use the Nix environment then my recommendation would be to set up a Python 2 environment with those specific versions of Numpy and PySparse.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I now get error: `No module named _multiarray_umath` see my updated question

Comment: I think I found the problem, I needed to install the new `numpy` version *before* I installed the `PySparse` version. Doing it the other way around, installing `PySparse` *before* `numpy` did not work.

Comment: Yes, PySparse requires the correct version of Numpy at both build time and run time.